# django model building table name wrong

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a postgresql RDS instance on aws free tier with my ec2 instance.  I should have used EB, but didn't really know about it until I had a lot built out and am not excited about starting over on a new ami.  I am trying to build my first interaction with the db, have a table there called server_config, created as:

```
CREATE TABLE SERVER_CONFIGS
(
  config_key VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL,
  config_value VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (config_key)
);
INSERT INTO SERVER_CONFIGS (config_key,config_value) 
  VALUES ('ClientMustVerify','TRUE');
INSERT INTO SERVER_CONFIGS (config_key,config_value) 
  VALUES ('Auditing','FALSE');
COMMIT;
```

and in my django app, I have:
models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class serverConfig(models.Model):

    config_key = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    config_value = models.CharField(max_length=63)
```

excerpt of view.py:

```
from limbo.models import serverConfig
def editServer(request):
    myConfigs = serverConfig.objects.all()
    configHtml = ""
    # for item in myConfigs #serverConfig.objects.values()
    #   configHtml += item.config_key + "\t" + item.config_value + "\n"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = serverForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            integer = form.cleaned_data['int_field']
            request.session['integer'] = integer

            # call out to limboLogic.py to update values, add them to the session
            message = 'The value \'' + str(integer) + '\' has been updated.'
            return render(request, 'limboHtml/ServerConfiguration.html', {'form': form, 'SubmitMessage': message, 'CurrentConfigs': myConfigs})
        else:
            message = 'The server configuration has NOT been updated.' + '\n'
            message += ', '.join("%s=%r" % (key,val) for (key,val) in form.errors.iteritems()) + '\n' 
            # message += ', '.join("%s=%r" % (key,val) for (key,val) in form.non_field_errors.iteritems()) + '\n' 
            return render(request, 'limboHtml/ServerConfiguration.html', {'form': form, 'SubmitMessage': message, 'CurrentConfigs': myConfigs})
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    try:
        del request.session['integer']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    form = serverForm()
    return render(request, 'limboHtml/ServerConfiguration.html', {'form': form, 'SubmitMessage': '', 'CurrentConfigs': myConfigs})
```

error message:

> File
>   "/home/ec2-user/limbo/limboenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
>   line 64, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ProgrammingError: relation "limbo_serverconfig" does not exist LINE 1: ...ig_key",
>   "limbo_serverconfig"."config_value" FROM "limbo_ser...

Why is it appending limbo_ at the start of the table?  any way I can change this?  should I just use my app name (or is that my project name?  they're called the same thing...stupid polls tutorial) in the tables?

Django 1.10 and python 2.7 on a linux ami on ec2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django creates a table for each of your models. The default name of the table will be `app_name + '_' + model_name`. If you do not want that to be the table's name, you can override it by specifying `db_table` in the models's Meta class

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#db-table

**Suggestion**

Please do not use the app with the same name as the project to write your application logic. That app should always contain only the project settings

Comment: that came up in one other place as I was trying to figure this out, but there's no evidence in sql workbench that such a table exists.  should I create the table as limbo_server_configs first?

Comment: @Keith First time when you setup a django project, you should create the database, and run `python manage.py syncdb` for `django <1.9` or `python manage.py migrate` for `django>=1.9`. this command creates all the required db tables. Before running that, make sure you do `python manage.py makemigrations` at first.

Comment: (limboenv)[ec2-user@ip-172-31-XX-XXX limboproj]$ python limbo/manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: @Keith did you do makemigrations?

Comment: yep:  `$ python limbo/manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
(limboenv)[ec2-user@ip-172-XX-XX-XXX limboproj]$ python limbo/manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.`

Comment: @Keith what django version do you use?

Comment: added that to my question above.  v1.10, python 2.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126850/discussion-between-aswin-murugesh-and-keith).

Comment: update: the reason I wasn't getting results from the select seems to be because the inserts via sql workbench weren't committed.